# A special rule for a directory in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

I'd like to create an exception of the last rule: if the user enters `example.com/somefoldername` It should not redirect to `index.php?p=somefoldername`, but to `./somefoldername/index.php`.

It is a very easy task I guess! But can't come up with a solution. I tried

`RewriteCond ^somefoldername$ somefoldername/index.php` but it didn't work.

Adding this line:

`RewriteCond ^(somefoldername)/?$ $1/index.php [L]`

causes "Internal Server error".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A bit of "a stab" at it (read: not looking at the documentation right now), but it'd be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1/index.php [QSA]
```

That being said, your conditions *already read* "if request filename is not a directory and request filename is not a file, then rewrite as this rule." So, if `somefoldername/index.pxp` already exists, it shouldn't even trigger this rewrite.